# The reaction navigate doesn't work, but there's no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { firebaseAuth } from "../firebase";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStatevalue } from "../services/StateProvider";

const Nav = () => {
  const [{user}, dispatch] = useStatevalue();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const menus = [
    { name: 'home', title: 'home' },
    { name: 'datemonth', title: 'board1' },
    { name: 'counseling', title: 'board2' },
    { name: 'wedding', title: 'board3' },
  ];

  const handleAuthentication = () => {
    if (user) {
      firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="tabs bg-white flex mt-4 sticky top-0 justify-center">
        {menus.map((menu) => {
          return (
            <Link to={`/${menu.name}`} key={menu.name}
            className="tab text-black border-black hover:text-red-500 hover:border-red-500 tab-bordered pb-10">
              {menu.title}
            </Link>
            );
          })}
        <Link to={!user && "/login"} className="flex-end tab pb-10 tab-bordered text-black border-black hover:border-red-500 hover:text-red-500">
          <span onClick={() => navigate("/mypage")}>{user ? "mypage" : "login"}</span>
        </Link>
          <span onClick={() => navigate("/mypage")}>mypage</span>
        {!user ? <Link to="/join" className="flex-end tab pb-10 tab-bordered text-black border-black  hover:text-red-500  hover:border-red-500">signUp</Link>: ""}
        <button onClick={handleAuthentication}>logout</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default Nav;
```

> > It's the entire code

```
<Link to={!user && "/login"} className="flex-end tab pb-10 tab-bordered text-black border-black hover:border-red-500 hover:text-red-500">
  <span onClick={() => navigate("/mypage")}>{user ? "mypage" : "login"}</span>
</Link>
```

> > This is the problem code

It's not working, but the 'navigate' in the 'span tag' below goes to the page, but the tag inserted in 'Link tag' can't go to the page and no errors appear I looked at the other code and referred to it, but is there a trinomial operator or something I wrote wrong?

```
const handleAuthmypage = () => {
    if (user) {
      
      navigate("/mypage");
      console.log("mypage");
    }
  };

<span onClick={handleAuthmypage}>{user ? "mypage" : "login"}</span>
```

I tried using the 'onClick()=>' arrow function, but 'console.log' is captured, but if you look at the address bar, it doesn't go to '/mypage' and stays there So it's hard to figure out "error"